# Is there a way to intercept Python module methods compiled into the interpreter?

Tags: python, multithreading, trace, interpreter, instrumentation

In general, it is possible to intercept Python (and even C) function calls and returns, and even bytecode execution using the [sys.setprofile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile) method in `sys` module.

However, some modules that come with Python are compiled directly into the interpreter; so some methods have their implementation in the C code rather than the Python code.
For instance in the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module which is a higher level module for the already built-in `_thread` C module, we have some synchronization methods that let us administer a mutex lock in order to avoid race conditions in multithreaded Python applications.

So one would call:

```
lock=threading.Lock()
lock.acquire()
# do something
lock.release()
```

or even context management is supported, is equivalent to:

```
lock=threading.Lock()
with lock:
    # do something
```

Unfortunately in the second case using the `with` statement, I am not able to know when the `__enter__()` function nor the `__exit()__` functions of the context manager are called [which are supposed to call `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()` respectively].

So they cannot be intercepted by debugging with `sys.setprofile()` [neither Python calls nor C function calls] just because a `threading.Lock()` object is fed into the `with` statement.

Any ideas how to achieve similar results **dynamically** WITHOUT static code analysis?